# Issues when migrating from Win XP to Win Vista a formerly working Delphi 5 application with 2 Dll

Tags: delphi, dll

I have an application in Delphi 5 which calls for 2 DLL. this works well in the. exe with Win XP. But when working with the IDE in the code of any of the DLL at the end of the main process marks an error **"raised too many consecutive exceptions"**. 
also in the file. exe with Windows Vista marks the error **"Sistema XXX has stopped working"** which I think may be due to the same thing happens in the IDE

this is the code main

```
unit DLLNiuxExplicit;

interface

const
  DLL_ModPpto = 'LIB_Pptos_Oper.dll';         // DLL Modulo Presupuesto
  DLL_ModCFD  = 'Prj_FE_Niux.dll';            // DLL Modulo Factura Electronica

var
{Variables de la funciones a utilizar en el proyecto}
  Configuracion : function (No_Orden : Integer; pathBD : WideString; PathDbConfig : Widestring) : Integer ; stdcall;
  Cotizar : function (No_Orden : Integer; pathBD : Widestring; PathDbConfig : Widestring) : Integer ; stdcall;
  GeneraCFD : function(No_Orden : Integer; PathBD : WideString; FechaLocal : WideString) : Integer ; stdcall;
  ImprimeCFD : function(BaseDatos : Widestring; No_Orden : Integer; Prefijo : WideString; No_Factura : Integer; Imprime : Boolean) : Boolean ; Stdcall;
  Fin_DLL_ModPpto : procedure stdcall;
  Fin_DLL_ModCFD : procedure stdcall;

implementation
uses
  Windows, Dialogs;
var
{Handles de Librerias}
  HLib : Cardinal;            // Handle de DLL del Modulo de Presupuestos
  HLibCFD : Cardinal;          // handle de DLL del Modulo de Factura Electronica
initialization
  HLib := LoadLibrary(DLL_ModPPto);
  if HLib <= 32 then
    MessageBox(0, 'Error : No puedo Cargar ' + DLL_ModPpto, 'Oops', MB_OK)
  else
    begin
      Configuracion := GetprocAddress(HLib, 'Modulo_PPtos_Configuracion');
      if not Assigned(Configuracion) then
        MessageBox(0, 'Error : No se Encontro la Funcion MODULO_PPTOS_CONFIGURACION ' ,'Oops', MB_OK);

      Cotizar := GetprocAddress(HLib, 'Modulo_Pptos_Operacion');
      if not Assigned(Cotizar) then
        MessageBox(0, 'Error : No se Encontro la Funcion MODULO_PPTOS_OPERACION ' ,'Oops', MB_OK);

      Fin_DLL_ModPpto := GetprocAddress(HLib, 'Fin_Lib_PPtos_Oper');
      if not Assigned(Fin_DLL_ModPpto) then
        MessageBox(0, 'Error : No se Encontro la Funcion Fin_Lib_PPtos_Oper ' ,'Oops', MB_OK);

    end;

  HLibCFD := LoadLibrary(DLL_ModCFD);
  if HLibCFD <= 32 then
    MessageBox(0, 'Error : No puedo Cargar ' + DLL_ModCFD, 'Oops', MB_OK)
  else
    begin
      GeneraCFD := GetprocAddress(HLibCFD, 'GenCFD');
      if not Assigned(GeneraCFD) then
        MessageBox(0, 'Error : No se Encontro la Funcion GenCFD ' ,'Oops', MB_OK);

      ImprimeCFD := GetprocAddress(HLibCFD, 'Prn_Factura');
      if not Assigned(ImprimeCFD) then
        MessageBox(0, 'Error : No se Encontro la Funcion Prn_Factura ' ,'Oops', MB_OK);

      Fin_DLL_ModCFD := GetprocAddress(HLibCFD, 'Fin_Prj_Fe_Niux');
      if not Assigned(Fin_DLL_ModCFD) then
        MessageBox(0, 'Error : No se Encontro la Funcion Fin_Prj_Fe_Niux ' ,'Oops', MB_OK);

    end;

finalization
  Fin_DLL_ModPpto;
  Fin_DLL_ModCFD;
  FreeLibrary(HLib);
  FreeLibrary(HLibCFD);
end.
```

this is the final code

```
procedure TFMain.SalidaExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
    //  Fin_DLL_ModPpto;
    //  Fin_DLL_ModCFD;
      Close;
end;
```

this is the final code of a DLL, both DLL are similar on functions

```
unit UFin_Lib_PPtos_Oper

interface
uses
  Sysutils;

procedure Fin_Lib_PPtos_Oper;

Exports Fin_Lib_PPtos_Oper;

implementation
uses
  UDmDatos,
  UPPtos_Oper,
  UCondiguracion;

procedure Fin_Lib_PPtos_Oper;
begin
  if assigned(DmDatos) then
   FreeAndNil(DmDatos);
  if assigned(Frm_PPtos_Oper) then
   FreeAndNil(Frm_PPtos_Oper);
  if assigned(frm_configuracion) then
   FreeAndNil(frm_configuracion);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense as posted, but the error is pretty clear. You've got zero exception handling in the DLL code. You should let **no** exceptions remain unhandled in the DLL. You need `try..except` blocks around everything that could possibly raise an exception, and need to handle the exceptions in whatever way is appropriate. If the DLL needs to inform the application of problems, it should return error codes when things don't work as expected.

Comment: Lots of odd things here. Your types are off. Use HMODULE rather than cardinal. <=32 is wrong. Error condition is =NULL. What's missing here is the creation of the form variables. I'm very suspicious of using VCL code with DLLs like this.

Comment: What are DmDatos, Frm_PPtos_Oper, and frm_configuration? Anything there that might be crashing? Can you possibly use English in the comments in your code? You should also make sure you use try..except and/or try..finally blocks to catch any exceptions - especially when playing with VCL from within a DLL.

Comment: Dmdatos is a TdataModule, Frm_PPtos_Oper, and frm_configuration are TForms. which are created dynamically when the function is called.modify the final block of the main application, and passes the try ... except, and sends the same error. I did the same modificaion in block output of the DLL with try ... except. also modifies hModule cardinal[code]try
//  Fin_DLL_ModPpto;
//  Fin_DLL_ModCFD;
  Close;
except
  on E: Exception do
   ShowMessage('Error al Finalizar DLL : ' + E.message);
[code]